# Calculating probability of decay

Tags: probability

In each gram of a radioactive probe, two atoms decay on average per minute. 
What is the probability that in one gram, more than two atoms will decay in one minute
I am not sure how to approach this question. Does this assumes some probability distribution 
function or we can do it without it.

Comment: Presumably this the probability of this happening in a random gram at a random time, not that this happens in any gram at any minute?

Comment: Do we have to assume some random variables here to find this out ? probably this has to be done without any distribution assumption.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: Radioactive decay assumes a Poisson distribution because it's independent of the last decay event.